# Maps on div not displaying properly when displayed through a Click function using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-maps

I have an anchor tag which when clicked will displays a div which contains a Map.

But its not getting displayed properly. Please check the below fiddle.
[Improper Display-jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/S9NEu/)

whereas if I display it at onload by setting `display:block` it will display properly as shown in the below fiddle.

[Proper Display-jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qn8NM/)

Why is it not getting displayed when its hidden and then showed up.

Here is the total code

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Page</title>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js">                  </script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () 
{
    $('#click').click(function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
    //$("#Maps").show();
    $("#Maps").css("display","block");
   })
});

</script>
</head>
<body>
<a href="#" id="click">Click Me</a>
<div id="Maps" runat="server" style="display:none;width: 100% !important; position:     fixed; z-index: 100000; margin-left: -10px; height: 100% !important; background-image: url('Images/Backgrounds/bgtrans.png')">

<div id="mapsdiv" runat="server">
<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m14!1m8!1m3!1d15530.128122214286!2d74.76403990607938!3d13.317147169095287!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x0%3A0x5a9e6eb499516618!2sSri+Mahalingeshwara+Temple%2C+Marpalli!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sin!4v1399292987193" width="800" height="600" frameborder="0" style="border:0"></iframe>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: That's because how maps script set its own properties depending container element relevant size

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you change the display state of a Google Map container, you need to redraw the map. Since you're using an embedded iframe, you don't have access to the map's `google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');` event.

As a workaround, you can simply set the iframe's `src` to itself after showing the map:

```
$('#click').click(function(){
    var $map = $('#Maps');

    $map.show();
    $map.find('iframe').attr('src', $map.find('iframe').attr('src'));
});
```

<kbd>[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/qn8NM/1/)</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

You could just set a class to put element outside viewport. This will avoid any extra useless reloading:

### DEMO

HTML:

```
<div id="Maps" class="outsideViewport">...</div>
```

CSS:

```
#Maps.outsideViewport{
    top: -99999px;
    left: -99999px;
}
```

Then:

```
$('#click').click(function () {
    $("#Maps").removeClass('outsideViewport');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't try to complicate the task you just don't need to use a block-type out of your map :

In #Maps use a `<span>` , and in jQuery instead of `show()` use `css("visibility", "visible");`

[DEMO HERE !](http://jsfiddle.net/S9NEu/3/)

Comment: Doesn't work on chrome. Even visibilty set to hidden on iframe, doesn't hide it. BTW, not sure why OP should use an inline-block element as span to contain an iframe?!

Comment: I'm on version 34 under Win7. Maybe this bug/behaviour has been fixed. Nice info then ;)

Answer (score 1):

Why dont you try the following:

**HTML**

```
<a href="#" id="click">Click Me</a>
<div id="Maps" style="">

<div id="mapsdiv">
        </div>      
    </div>
```

**JS**

```
$('#click').click(function(){
    $("#mapsdiv").html('<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m14!1m8!1m3!1d15530.128122214286!2d74.76403990607938!3d13.317147169095287!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x0%3A0x5a9e6eb499516618!2sSri+Mahalingeshwara+Temple%2C+Marpalli!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sin!4v1399292987193" width="800" height="600" frameborder="0" style="border:0"></iframe>');
   $("#Maps").show();
    $("#Maps").css("display","block");
   });
```

**CSS**

```
 #Maps{
        display:none;
        width: 100% !important; 
        position: fixed; 
        z-index: 100000; 
        margin-left: -10px; 
        height: 100% !important; 
    }
```

The idea is to add the map after you click the anchor tag, i took the code from your "not working fiddle", modified it to implement this solution, and it seems to get the result you want to achieve without the change being too traumatic to the overall code.

**FIDDLE**

http://jsfiddle.net/QNVg8/